# Remote Service is not Running from Nagios Monitoring Server

Tags: bash, shell, nagios, nrpe, nagiosxi

I am using Two VM.

First : Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (192.168.1.102)

Second : CentOS 7 (192.168.1.105)

On 192.168.1.102 I have Nagios Core v4.1.1, NagiosQL v3.2.0 and NRPE v2.15 are installed.

On 192.168.1.105 I have Apache Apollo and NRPE v2.15 are installed.

I already add 192.168.1.105 Host to Nagios Monitoring Server(192.168.1.102) Using NRPE Plugin using below link

http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-add-linux-host-to-nagios-monitoring-server/

I am able to check Apache Apollo service is running or not on 192.168.1.105(Nagios Monitoring Server) using below script from 192.168.1.102

```
#!/bin/bash

if pidof -x "apollo" >/dev/null; then
echo "Apollo MQTT is Running."
exit 0
else
echo "Apollo MQTT is Stopped."
exit 2
fi
```

But I want that if My Apache Apollo service is not running then I want to run this service. For this I modified the above script as below

```
#!/bin/bash

if pidof -x "apollo" >/dev/null; then
echo "Apollo MQTT is Running."
exit 0
else
echo "Apollo MQTT is Stopped."
servicestatus=sudo /etc/init.d/apollo-broker-service start
$servicestatus
exit 2
fi
```

But when i try to run this script from 192.168.1.102 Nagios using below command

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.105 -c check_service_apollomqtt
```

then output is below

```
Apollo MQTT is Stopped.
Starting apollo-broker-service
Could not start apollo-broker-service
```

I already add the below line in my 192.168.1.105 /etc/sudoers file

```
nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not using the service command at all.

1. Use 'which service' and make certain it is '/usr/sbin/service'.  Mine is located in a different folder.
2. Make certain that path/command from above is set correctly in your /etc/sudoers file.
3. Then modify your script to actually use the 'service' command, like:

**$servicestatus=sudo /sbin/service apollo-broker-service start**

Comment: like this "nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service apollo-broker-service"